# How to count if conditional with a group by in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of FinishedGames with columns: category and a score. I need to know how many games by category finished with more than certain score, but I don't understand the count if structure in PostgreSQL.

```
select category, count(score) as rounds, count(if score > 7) as wins
from "FinishedGames" group by category;
```

Does anyone knows how to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: we can use, `having <condition>` part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use the `CASE` clause within the count function.
e.g. `COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`
(or `SUM` with 1 and 0 - same result...)

Regards,
Jony

Comment: It works with count or sum. Thank you.